# Spark read multiple files and save as one output file

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am reading multiple files in Spark. Input:

```
path = glob.glob('/home/lh/workspace/PythonSpark/input/*/*')
textFile = sc.textFile(path)
```

The problem is it only seems to write to the output file the last file it is reading and not all of the files. I have tried coalesce(1) to collate them all but it behaves the same as without it.

```
wordCounts.saveAsTextFile("/home/lh/workspace/PythonSpark/output")
```

Comment: what about [wholeTextFiles](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=sparkcontext#pyspark.SparkContext.wholeTextFiles)?

Comment: If you require the file to be saved with saveAsTextFile you can use coalesce(1,true).saveAsTextFile(). This basically means do the computation then coalesce to 1 partition. You can also use repartition(1) which is just a wrapper for coalesce with the shuffle argument set to true

Comment: Thanks wholeTextFiles worked